# Private Node keeps disconnecting from public node

Tags: baker, private-mode, connections, public-node

I have a private node and a public node. I have added each other address in respective trust address list using below command:

```
./mainnet.sh admin-client trust address address_to_trust:9732
```

Initially the private node won't connect to public node so i have to use connect command from public node as mentioned below:

```
./mainnet.sh admin-client connect address address_to_connect:9732
```

Now my private node is connected to my public node and start syncing the blockchain. But the connection breaks after sometime automatically and syncing stops. This has happened thrice in 2 days.

I am not confident enough to start baking in private node if the only single connection breaks automatically.

Anything else i should do to ensure 24x7 connection uptime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Update 3/21/19 Core developers had pushed out a fix as of `366f64f3df266cf02a06412d6760f73626d0a2bf` commit on the `mainnet` branch that addresses this issue that I described below.*

> In the setting where you have a node in `--private-mode` (to bake)
>   that connects itself to front (public) nodes, you must explicitly set
>   your front nodes to trust your private node (using `--peer` argument
>   of `tezos-node` or the config file of `tezos-node` or RPCs)! Else,
>   there is a chance that at some point your front nodes decide to
>   disconnect themselves from your private node in favour of a fresh new
>   peer. The bug was that there were cases of disconnection of
>   trusted-private-peers (not really visible because nodes used to favour
>   old connections over new ones but still). we've now shielded those
>   connections.

Essentially, there is a new feature that allows you to set your private node as a peer on your public nodes. That will favor your private node over new peers on your public node.

---

*Original Answer*

This problem has been around since the beginning. The problem stems from that the private node is treated the same as every other peer in your public node(even setting one as trusted). Basically it's not prioritizing your private node higher and sometimes your public node may decide that your private node is less "useful" than others. I mean if you think about it, private nodes are just leechers, not really contributing to your public node(s) so your public node might disconnect your private node for another node in the network. Also if your private node somehow "misbehaves" such as not functioning correctly or taking up too much resources, your public node might even graylist it and not allow connections from your private node. Though you would expect setting as trusted should alleviate that!

Most of us early bakers solve this problem by increasing the number of redundancies(public nodes) so when one disconnects it's not a big deal and it should reconnect sooner or later. I think in general, this is a good idea as you'll likely need to upgrade your nodes and having no redundancy will make the process much trickier. These days, I actually find that my private node almost never disconnects unlike the early days. My suspicion is that the private node might have gain "credibility", kind of opposite of being graylisted.

Until a new feature is added that can ensure an undisrupted prioritized connection, your best options are really limited to bringing up more public nodes or adding the foundation nodes(likely trustworthy) as your trusted nodes. One thing you could try is [quicksync](https://www.tzdutch.com/quicksync/) or copy the chain data to your private node so you don't have to bootstrap your private node. It's possible that during the syncing process, it's getting disconnected due to the resources it's requiring. The problem could be your private node's workers, not your public node disconnecting it.

Comment: Can you specify list of trusted foundation nodes?

Comment: https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/723/can-someone-provide-list-of-trusted-foundation-nodes

Comment: how about running a script on our public node that keep checking the connection status with private node and if it finds no connection it runs a command to connect to private node automatically. Does this seems to be the solution apart from having multiple public nodes?

Comment: @SachinTomar that won't work because private nodes will reject external connections. Maybe it can work if you detect it on the private node side?

Comment: Actually i am facing opposite of what you said. When i run ./mainnet.sh admin-client connect address private-node-ip:9732  from public node, it creates a connection to private node.  But same command on private node with public-node ip in command fails with message "Cannot connect. Node is running in private node"       NOTE: i have added the public-node ip in peer list in private node.

Comment: How do you set the peer as trusted in "the config file of tezos-node"?

Comment: @Svante it's probably worth a different question to ask how to specify peers in the node config file.

Comment: @Frank Good idea, done: https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/1102/how-can-i-set-trusted-peers-by-identity-in-the-tezos-node-config-file

Answer (score 4):

While this does not directly answer your question, Kiln has a feature that can notify you when your Private Node loses connections.

When you configure Kiln to monitor the Private Node, include a 'minimum number of peers' in the UI. If your Private Node's peers drop below that number, you'll receive a notification.

https://gitlab.com/obsidian.systems/tezos-bake-monitor

Comment: Thanks. Setting monitoring and alerting really helps to ensure our node is running in healthy state. I don't need to check my node again and again now.