# Can someone provide list of trusted foundation nodes?

Tags: private-mode, connections, public-node, foundation-nodes

I have my private node which keeps disconnecting from my public node. So I need list of trusted foundation nodes which i can connect to my private node so my private node uptime does not hamper if 1 or 2 connections breaks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Command to add trusted nodes to config**

This is how I configure the node to use these "trusted nodes". I added the command to open up to 500 connections which can be left out of course:

```
./tezos-node config update \
--peer="dubnodes.tzbeta.net:9732" \
--peer="franodes.tzbeta.net:9732" \
--peer="sinnodes.tzbeta.net:9732" \
--peer="nrtnodes.tzbeta.net:9732" \
--peer="pdxnodes.tzbeta.net:9732" \
--connections 500
```

Comment: Please note that this will not get all the individual nodes behind those DNS names. See my answer for an alternative.

Answer (score 6):

Here is whats in my consig.json:

```
"dubnodes.tzbeta.net ", "franodes.tzbeta.net ", "sinnodes.tzbeta.net" , " nrtnodes.tzbeta.net"
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the full list given by the maintainer of the foundation nodes:

```
dubnodes.tzbeta.net
franodes.tzbeta.net
sinnodes.tzbeta.net
nrtnodes.tzbeta.net
pdxnodes.tzbeta.net
```

I use those mainly.

Answer (score 1):

Behind the known DNS addresses are several individual IPs with the nodes. Therefore you should use dig (from package dnsutils on debian) to connect to all of them.

When running a node in *private* mode, you also need to trust the address first.

Also it might be a good idea to put these nodes into your default config. See the commented alternative line.

```
  # get foundation nodes
  for i in dubnodes franodes sinnodes nrtnodes pdxnodes; do
      for j in `dig $i.tzbeta.net +short`; do
        # assume default port
        address="[$j]:9732"
        # trust new address if in private mode
        tezos-admin-client -A localhost trust address "${address}"
        tezos-admin-client -A localhost connect address "${address}"
        # alternative: Add to node config
        # tezos-node config update --peer="${address}"
      done
  done
```