# How can I set trusted peers by identity in the tezos-node config file?

Tags: node, config

I found the "example configuration file with all parameters specified" here: https://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/introduction/various.html

But I can't find any config entry doing the equivalent of `./tezos-admin-client trust peer id12345abcde`.

What is the syntax to set trusted peers by their identity in the tezos-node config file?

Answer (score 1):

Their is currently no way to set a trusted peer by its ID in the node configuration file.

If your peer has been set trusted through RPC and that your node was shutdown properly, the information is stored in the peers.json file and should be restored on node reboot, but I wouldn't rely on that.