# tezos-admin-client trust peer VS tezos-node config update --peer

Tags: private-mode, private, p2p, peers

On a private node, is there an effective difference between using `./tezos-admin-client trust peer id12345abcde` and `./tezos-node config update --peer=IP:PORT`?

In other words, if you use the latter, is there an advantage to also using the former?

PS: [the latter is the only way to make it stick](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/a/1139/29). the former cannot be put into the config file, you can only hope that it will remain in peers.json (or you could cron the cmd every so often).